# Windows 10 Quick Launch icons showing as 'blank page'

Tags: windows-10

Attached is a picture of the Quick Launch bar on my windows 10 setup.  The top image (I added red arrows) shows three of the icons as kind of ‘blank page’ icon.  This happens every time I reboot.  If I click on one, the icon shows up (look at the second picture, I clicked on the left most ‘blank page’ icon – it is the command prompt).

[image: QuickLaunchIconsMissing]

Anyone know how I can fix this so they show up after I boot?

Answer (score 3):

The following should solve your problem:

### To Rebuild the Icon Cache in the Command Prompt:

> 1. Close and save anything that you are working on before proceeding. The next  Steps will involve killing explorer and restarting the PC.
> 2. Open an elevated command prompt.
> 3. Copy and paste each command below one at a time into the command prompt, and press **Enter** after each command.
>
> Note: **The last command will instantly restart the PC.**
>
> 1. ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
> 2. taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
> 3. DEL `"%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A`
> 4. shutdown /r /f /t 00

[Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Sorry - didn't work for me.

Comment: did not work for me either

Comment: In my testing it worked for me.

Comment: @Ramhound How do you recreate the problem??

Comment: @Valay_17 - I wrote this answer more than 4 years ago.  I couldn't say, but I know I would have only written an answer, that I knew worked.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought that there exists an application or something where one can recreate such problems, also I still think that there exists an application only for the ones working at support centers where they can actually recreate such problems and provide solutions accordingly. Silly thought but nevermind.

Comment: @Valay_17 - That does not seem relevant to my answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes just wanted to know if recreation of problems is actually a thing because you mentioned in my testing, so I just kinda assumed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the same as Ramhound's answer above, but doesn't need admin privileges or the command line. My work PC had this issue, and I don't have admin rights on it. Found the answer here: https://consumer.huawei.com/lb/support/content/en-us00698750/

Instructions in case the link fails:

1. Press the Win and R keys at the same time to access the Run window. Enter "%localappdata%" and click OK.
2. The icon cache file is a hidden file, click View then select Hidden items if not already done.
3. Right-click Iconcache.db then select Delete.
4. Right-click the taskbar then click Task Manager.
5. Right-click File Explorer then select Restart.

My icons were fixed without needing to reboot the PC

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by putting the right path in the "Start in" field of each program.
Right click -> Properties -> Shortcut -> Start in
Put the path to the program (between quotation marks if it contains spaces)
i.e: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16" for Office 2016

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this, solution was easier than expected. The icon rebuild did not work for me. changing the icon to a generic system icon would work but then switching back to the desired icon (provided by an exe file, so not an  .ico file ) it would go back to the white page.

I noticed changing the icon kept asking for Admin permission which seemed odd as it was just an HP scanner app and shouldn't really need Admin permissions.

Some how the customer just removed all access permission from the shortcut for their user.

Right click the icon > properties > security

Add full control to the appropriate user.

Worked for me, hopefully that'll help some one else out there too

Answer (score -1):

I just right clicked on the open office short cut on the desk top and went to properties then change icon picture ...then dragged it to task bar and the short cut  showed under the icon i changed it to

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).